# How do I update a UITextView in my view controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have tried to use

```
self.myUITextView.text = @"hi";
```

to update my UITextView in my Nib file.

However, the original text of the UITextView is still on the screen. How do I update a UITextView in my view controller?

Comment: I have this in viewDidLoad by the way. Hence, the text should update upon loading of the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure you must have declared the UITextView as

```
IBOutlet UITextView *myUITextView;
```

and also properly connected it to your XIB.

Then declare the following property in your .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *myUITextView;
```

and synthesize it in your .m file

```
@synthesize myUITextView;
```

Now try to change the text to whatever you want. In your case

```
myUITextView.text = @"hi";
```

Answer (score 4):

Give proper connection (IBOutLet) from xib to your view controller. You have missed the IBOutLet connection of UITextView from nib to controller as i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set property of uitextview [self.myUITextView setText:@"Hi Updated"];

in -(Void)viewWillApper method.

Comment: this will not clear the initial text that is present on the text view

Comment: Dear @Justin Case thanks for downvote, I create an app with a uiviewcontroller and put UITextview on a view and declare

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your UITextView IBOutlet in IB is hooked up with a valid connection to your controller's property.
2. Wait until "viewDidLoad" is called to change the text (before that, you have no guarantee the text view is loaded in memory).
3. Change the text property (as you did).

Answer (score -1):

You are doing wrong thing....You are specifying value in load method...So even though you have changed the value, when you try to load that view again...viewDidload method will be called and the new value will be replaced by the original value....

Instead of setting value in viewDidload..Make some method or put some button ang in its click method,Set the value and store it somewhere......You are doing totally wrong thing.

Comment: this is not the answer. There are different situations in which textfield & textview are used. One cant blankly suggest when to use it without prior knowledge about requirement.

Comment: @hpiOSCoder - yup.....Before your comment I have edited my answer.Thanks for downvote