# Change content in UITextView

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitextview

Quite a simple one I assume but searching has failed me.

I have a UITextView I set up in a Storyboard with some dummy text. Dynamically I would like to change the content of this, but I don't know how. Searching for this seems to only returns results in which the UITextView has been created programmatically as opposed to via a drag and drop on the Storyboard, hence they have direct access to a variable representing it.

Comment: Please follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136371/how-do-i-update-a-uitextview-in-my-view-controller

Comment: An outlet, of course. I knew about this actually, but had a complete brain blank... Is it worth answering my own question, or should I just delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an outlet to UITextView then changed it dynamically!

Like this:

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *yourText;

self.yourText.text = // ANY TEXT HERE